# when mounting volume, directory is empty in docker

Tags: docker, node-red

when I run nodered with

```
docker run -v D:/mydir:/data
```

the content of /data is copied in my volume at first run, thats what I've expected.

If I make

```
docker run -v D:/mydir:/usr/src/node-red/node_modules nodered
```

Then the volume is empty

I was expecting to get the content of node_modules being copied in the volume at start time... what am I missing ?

---

I can illustrate that a little bit more :

```
docker run --rm -v d:/VM:/data nodered/node-red-docker ls /data
```

--> list files

```
docker run --rm  ls /usr/src/node-red/node_modules
```

--> list content of node_modules

```
docker run --rm -v d:/VM:/usr/src/node-red/node_modules nodered/node-red-docker ls /usr/src/node-red/node_modules
```

--> is empty !

Comment: I'm afraid the Docker docs say that what you're trying to do isn't supported.
See the first point here:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#/data-volumes

Can you explain what you're trying to achieve and I'll see if I can find an alternative way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mounting host directories as volumes, so there isn't any copying going on - the mount path inside the container is being mapped to the path on the host, so you're seeing the contents of the host directory.

Volumes sit outside the Union File System when you mount them, so you don't get an overlay which merges the contents of the image and the contents of the host directory. Instead you're effectively bypassing the contents of the image for that volume, and repointing it to your host.

Samples:

```
touch /docker/nodered-modules/sample.txt                                           
docker run --rm -v /docker/nodered-modules:/usr/src/node-red/node_modules nodered/node-red-docker ls /usr/src/node-red/node_modules                                         
sample.txt

touch /docker/nodered-data/sample.txt                                                                                                         
docker run --rm -v /docker/nodered-data:/data nodered/node-red-docker ls /data       
sample.txt
```

The reason you're seeing a difference is because the `/data` volume is [defined in the Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/nodered/node-red-docker/~/dockerfile/) and empty in the image, so you see the contents of your host directory as expected. The `modules` directory isn't empty in the image, but you're repointing it to an empty directory on your host.

Answer (score 0):

Docker [does not support copying](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#/data-volumes) data from the base image into host directories that are mounted as container volumes.